# How to prevent POST through socket in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, csrf

Is there a way to prevent POST to URL through sockets in PHP? I knew all about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF but I don't want to put a hidden input with a unique hash on any form, I just want to prevent globally POST to any URL of my script from a remote host or any other client.
I have a way to prevent POST via cURL by checking HTTP_EXPECT and REQUEST_METHOD, but when script called by a client through a socket connection there isn't any special parameter that I can decision about it, actually there is no difference between normal POST or POST via socket.
If you try POST to http://www.google.com through a socket you will get a **HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed** error, everything that I need is the same way on my PHP script.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot tell the difference between a request from a browser and a request from curl pretending to be a browser.  What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: In fact there is a difference between call by cURL and browser, but I can't find any difference when that is opened by a socket like **fsockopen** in PHP or other language that support sockets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if got your question. You can use `mod_rewrite` to forbid all `POST` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST 
RewriteRule .* /yourerrordocuments/405.html [R=405,L]
```

Put this in your `.htaccess`. It will disable all post requests.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I don't want to prevent POST completely, I just need to process POST through any scripts on my website and drop any POST request from external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

@hek2mgl is the best solution for all your scripts, but per-script, you could try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
  die();
}
else
{
  echo 'continue';
}
?>
```

Comment: This will not work. I expect that `$_POST` will be set even on `GET` request. You should test `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'`